# How to use linq to parse xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

Here i my xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Ftpservers>
  <Ftpserver>
    <Name>Client1</Name>
    <ServerIP>10.10.10.100:1961</ServerIP>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <Password>pa$#word1</Password>
    <EnableSSL>false</EnableSSL>
    <UsePassive>false</UsePassive>
</Ftpserver>
  <Ftpserver>
    <Name>Client2</Name>
    <ServerIP>10.10.10.101:1961</ServerIP>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <Password>pa$#word1</Password>
    <EnableSSL>false</EnableSSL>
    <UsePassive>false</UsePassive>
  </Ftpserver>
</Ftpservers>
```

and here is my c# code:-

```
    public class FtpInfo
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ServerIp { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public bool EnableSsl { get; set; }
            public bool UsePassive { get; set; }
        }

var xmlReader = XDocument.Load("FtpDestination.xml");
var servers = (from f in xmlReader.Descendants("FtpServer")
            select new FtpInfo
            {
                Name = f.Element("Name").Value,
                ServerIp = f.Element("ServerIP").Value,
                UserName = f.Element("UserName").Value,
                Password = f.Element("Password").Value,
                EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("EnableSSL").Value),
                UsePassive = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("UsePassive").Value)
            }).ToList<FtpInfo>();
foreach(var server in servers)
    Console.Write(server.Name);
```

I am trying to read an xml file using xdocument class. but unable to find why my servers count is always zero. Code does not throw any error but not reading xml data at all. 
Please advice?

Comment: you should put a try-catch around the code and you would see the errors easily in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code,

1. First it is `Ftpserver` not `FtpServer` as in your code. *(notice the lower case server)*
2. Second, You are using `Name` for `UsePassive`

In line:

```
UsePassive = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("Name").Value)
```

It should be `UsePassive`

```
UsePassive = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("UsePassive").Value)
```

Last, although it is not an error, but you don't need `.ToList<FtpInfo>();` only  `ToList` is enough.

So your statement should be:

```
var servers = (from f in xmlReader.Descendants("Ftpserver")
               select new FtpInfo
               {
                   Name = f.Element("Name").Value,
                   ServerIp = f.Element("ServerIP").Value,
                   UserName = f.Element("UserName").Value,
                   Password = f.Element("Password").Value,
                   EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("EnableSSL").Value),
                   UsePassive = Convert.ToBoolean(f.Element("UsePassive").Value)
               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

UsePassive is failing you in its Boolean conversion, change from `Name` to `UsePassive`.

Answer (score 2):

Your Xml nodes are "Ftpserver" but you are querying for "FtpServer".  The query therefore returns zero result elements.